# Can't call function with vararg param and not vararg params from java

Tags: android, kotlin

in my android project I use java and kotlin  code:

In Kotlin code:

```
fun getOperationsList(vararg typesList: OperationType, operationStatusList: List<OperationStatus>) {
...
}
```

Here java code:

```
List<OperationStatus> operationStatusList = new ArrayList<>();
        operationStatusList.add(OperationStatus.EXECUTED);
    TransportService.INSTANCE.getOperationsList(OperationType.PAYMENT, OperationType.PAYOUT, operationStatusList);
```

But I get compile error in java code:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation processors are not incremental: jetified-androidannotations-4.6.0.jar (org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.6.0).
Consider setting the experimental feature flag android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file to run annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation incremental.
warning: A class activity declared in the AndroidManifest.xml cannot be found in the compile path: [com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity]
fragment\navigation\ReportsFragment.java:122: error: method getOperationsList in class TransportService cannot be applied to given types;
        TransportService.INSTANCE.getOperationsList(OperationType.PAYMENT, OperationType.PAYOUT, operationStatusList);
                                 ^
  required: OperationType[],List<? extends OperationStatus>
  found: OperationType,OperationType,List<OperationStatus>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
1 warning

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Kotlin uses Arrays to represent varargs.

```
 TransportService.INSTANCE.getOperationsList(
   new OperationType[]{ OperationType.PAYMENT, OperationType.PAYOUT }, 
   operationStatusList
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in `Kotlin` `vararg` parameter should be the last one, in order to achieve wanted semantics :

```
fun getOperationsList(operationStatusList: List<OperationStatus>,
                      vararg typesList: OperationType) {
...
}
```